# Update cursor returned by ContentProvider.query() for android TV search

Tags: android, cursor, android-search, android-searchmanager, android-tv

I'm implementing search in my app and using a `ContentProvider` to provide search suggestions for that. I'm doing everything like here: 
 
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/searchable.html

My implementation is based on that:
https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback 
where `ContentProvider` is implemented.

My `ContentProvider` is returning `MatrixCursor` with 10 elements and I would like to update this `Cursor` in the future adding new elements. I've tried to do that implementing new `Thread` in which after return `MatrixCursor` by `query()` I insert new element every second using `MatrixCursor.addRow()`. But I can see only 10 first items in the suggestion row. What's the problem with that? Why doesn't it work? Any suggestions? What's happening to the `Cursor` returned by `query()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find out more about this?

Comment: I'm interested in the same issue, have you find a solution?